# Android Floating Context Menu get item clicked

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to write a floating context menu for a grid view in fragmentActivity. I want to get the item on which the user clicks. I've gone through many posts, all of them say to use getMenuInfo() method in onContextItemSelected, but it is always null in my case .. can anyone help ?

In onCreate I'm doing this-

```
registerForContextMenu(mGridView);
```

Context Menu Methods -

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an option");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Hide");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Info");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position; // Null pointer Exception

    if(item.getTitle()=="Hide") {
            hideview(item.getItemId());
            return true;
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Info"){
            showinfo(item.getItemId());
            return true;
    }
    else{
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working finally.

Issue was, I was using custom GridView in which `getContextMenuInfo()` method was not implemented. I've added below lines and it worked perfectly -

```
@Override
protected ContextMenuInfo getContextMenuInfo(){
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo = super.getContextMenuInfo();
    if(menuInfo==null){
        final ListAdapter adapter = mAdapter;
        final int motionPosition = mPerformClick.mClickMotionPosition;
        if (adapter != null && mItemCount > 0 &&
                motionPosition != INVALID_POSITION &&
                motionPosition < adapter.getCount()) {
            final View view = getChildAt(motionPosition);

            if (view != null) {
                final int clickPosition = motionPosition + mFirstPosition;
                menuInfo = new AdapterContextMenuInfo(view, clickPosition, 
                                                 adapter.getItemId(clickPosition));
            }
        }
    }
    return menuInfo;
}
```

I've posted a small tutorial [here](http://vinaybhargav.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-floating-context-menu-for-listviewgridview/) just in case if someone needs it.